# Entity Framework connection string error in Azure

Tags: entity-framework, azure, connection-string

I am currently running into a error upon deploying to Azure.
I took the connection string directly from my web config file, which works when testing locally, and i modified it to fit my deployment to Azure, but then i get an error.

**Below is the original connection string that works on my local machine:**

```
<add name="DataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.FirearmModels.csdl|res://*/Models.FirearmModels.ssdl|res://*/Models.FirearmModels.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Data.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**Below is the modified connection string for Azure:**

```
<add name="DataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.FirearmModels.csdl|res://*/Models.FirearmModels.ssdl|res://*/Models.FirearmModels.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:owm5115h08.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=diafirearmserver;User ID=userid;Password=userpass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Could someone please tell me what i am doing wrong, what i am missing, in getting this to work?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Here's a screenshot of the error i get when i run it in Azure:
http://i693.photobucket.com/albums/vv293/saturobi360/EntityConnString_Error_zpsyrt1f9jg.jpg

My apologies on the quality of the image.
My apologies:

```
    <Error>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>
    An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
    </ExceptionMessage>
    <ExceptionType>
    System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException
    </ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.<ExecuteStoreCommandsAsync>d__c.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.<ExecuteAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__3d`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__9`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<GetResultsAsync>d__e.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator`1.<FirstMoveNextAsync>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.<FirstOrDefaultAsync>d__25`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at DIA_FirearmsAPIversion2.Controllers.FirearmsController.<GetFirearm>d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
    <InnerException>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>Invalid object name 'dbo.Firearms'.</ExceptionMessage>
    <ExceptionType>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException</ExceptionType>
    <StackTrace>
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c__DisplayClass16.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__17(Task`1 result) at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.<ExecuteStoreCommandsAsync>d__c.MoveNext()
    </StackTrace>
    </InnerException>
```

**My original connection string for local:**

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-DIA_FirearmsAPIversion2-20151118042347.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-DIA_FirearmsAPIversion2-20151118042347;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.FirearmModels.csdl|res://*/Models.FirearmModels.ssdl|res://*/Models.FirearmModels.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Data.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="DIA_FirearmsAPIversion2Context" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=DIA_FirearmsAPIversion2Context-20151118164215; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DIA_FirearmsAPIversion2Context-20151118164215.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**My connection string to Azure:**

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:owm5115h08.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=diafirearmserver;User Id=username;Password=userpassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.FirearmModels.csdl|res://*/Models.FirearmModels.ssdl|res://*/Models.FirearmModels.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:owm5115h08.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=diafirearmserver;User ID=username;Password=userpassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="DIA_FirearmsAPIversion2Context" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:owm5115h08.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=diafirearmserver;User Id=username;Password=userpassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: On my phone, that image is terrible. Cut and paste the exception into your question to make life easier for all concerned.

Comment: @BrendanGreen, my apologies on the image quality of the screenshot. I updated the original post with the error.

Comment: On publishing to azure you have the option to run pending migrations, have you selected this check box? Also try connecting to your sql database and see what's actually there (tables)...

Comment: @Milen Pavlov, when i try connecting to the database in Azure to see what's actually there i get the following error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.)

No such host is known

Comment: @MilenPavlov I have updated the original post to show what my original connection strign for local is, which works fine, and my modified connection string for Azure.

Comment: you might be getting error while trying to connect to database because your IP address is not allowed in. You can change this in Azure Portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error seems to suggest that you don't have automatic migrations/database migrations have not been run on your azure version of the database.
Mainly you added a "Firearms" table but the azure table doesn't contain this table

Comment: Thanks @Batavia, 

Now i get a:
Can not override the connection for this context with a standard DbConnection because the original connection was an EntityConnection

Comment: @saturobi360, I am facing the same problem here. Could you please share what you did to resolve the issue? Thanks